# Room using the @Relation annotation - one to many relationship where clause child relationship

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

Using the @Relation annotation. I can query a one to many relationship using the following:

```
 @Dao
 public interface PostDao {
        @Query("SELECT * FROM post")
        List<PostWithComments> getPostWithComments();
 }
```

Here are the entities

```
@Entity
public class Post {
    @PrimrayKey
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String content;
}

@Entity
public class Comment {
    @PrimrayKey
    private int id;
    private int post_id;
    private String content;
    private String status;
}


public class PostWithComments {
    @Embedded
    public Post post;

    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "post_id", entity = Comment.class)
    public List<Comment> comments;

}
```

I would like to get all posts that have a comment with `status = approved` but I'm not exactly sure how room handles this. I tried the following:

```
 @Dao
 public interface PostDao {
        @Query("SELECT * FROM post INNER JOIN comment ON post.id = comment.post_id WHERE comment.status = 'approved'")
        List<PostWithComments> getPostWithComments();
 }
```

I got duplicates in the results. Each post is there multiple times in `List<PostWithComments>` results.

**Update:**

After reading the generated code at `PostDao_Impl.java` it seems that Room is doing a sub query to fetch the relation.

First, it executes the query in the `@Query` annotation from the `getPostWithComments` method, and then it generates a sub query for the relation to populate `List<Comment>`

`SELECT id, post_id, title, content FROM comment WHERE post_id IN (` and some other logic, and there doesn't seem to be a way to modify the generated sub query.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: For the meantime, maybe you can filter the resulting comments.

Comment: @uan that's what I'm doing but ideally I should be able to filter those in the query.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With @Relation, you can use [@DatabaseView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/DatabaseView)

```
@DatabaseView("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE status = 'approved'")
public class ApprovedComment {
  @Embedded
  Comment comment;
}
```

PostWithComments class

```
public class PostWithComments {
    @Embedded
    public Post post;

    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "post_id", entity = ApprovedComment.class)
    public List<ApprovedComment> comments;

}
```

DAO

```
@Dao
public interface PostWithCommentsDao {
       @Query("SELECT * FROM post")
       List<PostWithComments> getPostWithComments();
}
```

You also need to update your Database class that extends RoomDatabase and you may need to update the version.

```
@Database(entities = {Post.class, Comment.class}, views = {ApprovedComment.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class MyDatabase extends RoomDatabase
```

Comment: Great answer, works perfectly.
Please note that this is also the way to use an _order by_ clause for child entities in a relationship : add the order by to the DatabaseView query.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but you can try this...

```
public class PostWithComments {
    @Embedded
    public Post post;

    @Embedded
    public Comment comment;
}



@Dao
public interface PostWithCommentsDao {
       @Query("SELECT post.*, comment.* FROM post LEFT JOIN comment ON post.id=comment.post_id where comment.status = 'approved'")
       List<PostWithComments> getPostWithComments();
}
```

Comment: How is this supposed to work? Each post has multiple comments not one. PostWithComments object must have a single post and a list of comments.