# Room @Relation with nested dynamic WHERE clause

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-room-relation

Suppose I have items which can each have many categories:

```
@Entity(tableName = "items")
data class Item(
        @PrimaryKey val item_id: Long,

        val external_id: String,

        val name: String,

        val price: Long,

        val image: String?,

        var indexInResponse: Int = -1

)

@Entity(tableName = "categories")
data class Category(
        @PrimaryKey val cat_id: Long,

        val name: String,

        val image: String?,

        var indexInResponse: Int = -1
)


//-------
@Entity(tableName = "items_with_categories", primaryKeys = ["item", "cat"], indices = [Index(value = ["cat"])])
data class ItemCategoryCrossRef(
        val item: Long,
        val cat: Long
)

data class ItemWithCategories(
        @Embedded val item: Item,
        @Relation(
                parentColumn = "item_id",
                entityColumn = "cat_id",
                associateBy = Junction(
                        ItemCategoryCrossRef::class,
                        parentColumn = "item",
                        entityColumn = "cat")
        )
        val cats: List<Category>
)
```

And I can retrieve all items with categories using this, which works well:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY indexInResponse ASC")
abstract fun getItemsWithCategories(): DataSource.Factory<Int, ItemWithCategories>
```

How can I retrieve items with particular categories based on ID using Room or SQL?

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE ??<something>?? LIKE :catID ORDER BY indexInResponse ASC")
abstract fun getItemsWithCategoriesByCatID(catID: Long): DataSource.Factory<Int, ItemWithCategories>
```

I don't think this is possible, obviously the list of Categories is a list of POJOs, and it's a nested relation. So is the only way to do this in SQL to do it with a raw query?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56387552/room-using-the-relation-annotation-one-to-many-relationship-where-clause-chil) is the closest question I have found, but the DatabaseView in the answer here uses a hard coded field for it's WHERE clause and I need to be able to specify the category ID at run time.